# Convert json dict

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have pulled JSON data from a url. The result is a dictionary. How can I transform this dictionary so metric is a column, and the time is the index for each value

Thanks in advance

```
time------------------------AdrActCnt-----BlkCnt------BlkSizeByte

2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z----1097896.0-----145.0-------190568423.0
2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z----1208741.0-----152.0-------199725189.0
2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z----1087755.0-----136.0-------177349536.0

Output:   

{"metricData":{"metrics":["AdrActCnt","BlkCnt","BlkSizeByte"],"series": 
[{"time":"2021-01-28T00:00:00Z","values"["1097896.0","145.0","190568423.0"]}, 
{"time":"2021-01-29T00:00:00Z","values":["1208741.0","152.0","199725189.0"]}, 
{"time":"2021-01-30T00:00:00Z","values":["1087755.0","136.0","177349536.0"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a dict comprehension, which is similar to a list comprehension, just creates a dictionary at the end:

```
liststuff = [{"time":"2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z","values":["1097896.0","145.0","190568423.0"]},{"time":"2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z","values":["1208741.0","152.0","199725189.0"]},{"time":"2021-01-30T00:00:00.000Z","values":["1087755.0","136.0","177349536.0"]}]
dictstuff = {item['time']:item['values'] for item in liststuff}
print(dictstuff)
```

> ```
> {'2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z': ['1097896.0', '145.0', '190568423.0'], '2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z': ['1208741.0', '152.0', '199725189.0'], '2021-01-30T00:00:00.000Z': ['1087755.0', '136.0', '177349536.0']}
> ```

`liststuff` is your data, just needed `[]` wrapping (I assume that's a typo in the question, it's not valid JSON without the brackets). If you need help with parsing the string, use `json.loads()` (from the `json` module) to make it actual Python data:

```
import json
jsonstuff = '[{"time":"2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z","values":["1097896.0","145.0","190568423.0"]},{"time":"2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z","values":["1208741.0","152.0","199725189.0"]},{"time":"2021-01-30T00:00:00.000Z","values":["1087755.0","136.0","177349536.0"]}]'
liststuff = json.loads(jsonstuff)
```

(here `jsonstuff` is the string you've downloaded)